# TypeError: (0, _react.default) is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using codesandbox.io for my application and it returns error **TypeError**: (0, *_react.default*) is not a function. This main `App.js` code was working fine until I tried to import **useState** from react, like this.

```
// The error reference appears on the line that is defined by the isOpen variable and the openSidebar function

import useState, {React} from "react";
export default function App () {
  const [isOpen, openSidebar] = useState (false);
  return (
```

**isOpen** and **openSidebar** is used in

```
    <Sidebar
      sidebar = {
            <>
              <h1> Sidebar content </h1> 
              <h1> Sidebar content </h1> 
              <h1> Sidebar content </h1> 
              <h1> Sidebar content </h1>
            </>
      }
      open = {isOpen}
      styles = {{sidebar: {background: "white", height: "100%"}}}
    >
      <Button onClick = {openSidebar (! IsOpen)}> Open sidebar </Button>
    </Sidebar>
```

File:

```
import "./styles.css";

import {Navbar, Nav, Container, Button} from "react-bootstrap";
import Sidebar from "react-sidebar";

import React, {useState} from "react";

export default function App () {

  const [isOpen, openSidebar] = useState (false);

  return (
    <div className = "App">
      <Navbar bg = "dark" style = {{color: "white", zIndex: 100}}>
        <Container>
          <Navbar.Brand href = "# home" style = {{color: "gray"}}>
            home
          </Navbar.Brand>
          <Nav className = "me-auto">
            <Nav.Link href = "# home" style = {{color: "gray"}}>
              Info
            </Nav.Link>
          </Nav>
        </Container>
      </Navbar>
      <div>
        <Sidebar
          sidebar = {
            <>
              <h1> Sidebar content </h1> 
              <h1> Sidebar content </h1> 
              <h1> Sidebar content </h1> 
              <h1> Sidebar content </h1>
            </>
          }
          open = {isOpen}
          styles = {{sidebar: {background: "white", height: "100%"}}}
        >
          <Button onClick = {() => openSidebar(!IsOpen)}> Open sidebar </Button>
        </Sidebar>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I think restarting the sandbox may fix some bugs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`React` is the default export and `useState` is a named export.  So change your import line to

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```